# Degrees of Freedom covariance

Tags: covariance, degrees-of-freedom

I have troubles understanding the concept of degrees of freedom, especially in the case of the covariance. In the case of the standard deviation I think I understand why I have to divide the quadratic sum of the differences to the mean by $(n-1)$. There is one degree less since I have to estimate the expected value. In the case of the covariance the denominator is still $(n-1)$ but I have to estimate two expected values. Why isn't it $n-2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "degrees of freedom" argument is esoteric and only useful as a vague argument in the first chapter of a statistic text book because the actual reason cannot yet be explained to beginners. Unfortunately, this "explanation" leads to more confusion than plainly admitting that the beginner cannot yet understand it.

The actual reason for the correction is, that it makes the estimator unbiased. It is
$$E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline{x})^2\right) = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$$

Multiply this equation with $n/(n-1)$, and you obtain an unbiased estimator for the variance.

**Edit (for pundits):** and here is the counterexample mentioned in the comments below that confutes the "degree of freedoms" argumentation for the denominator in the variance.

From the measured values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, let us use only the first value $x_1$ as an estimator for the expectation value $\mu$. This estimator is unbiased because $E(x_1)=\mu$, although its variance is by a factor $n$ greater than the variance of $\overline{x}$, so this is merely a toy example. Nevertheless, we can build a variance estimator upon this estimator for $\mu$, namely
$$s'^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_1)^2$$
Now let us check, whether this estimator is unbiased:
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(s'^2) & = & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left((x_i-x_1)^2\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left([(x_i-\mu) - (x_1-\mu)]^2\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \Big[ \underbrace{E\left((x_i-\mu)^2\right)}_{\sigma^2} - 2 E\left((x_i-\mu)(x_1-\mu\right) + \underbrace{E\left((x_1-\mu)^2\right)}_{\sigma^2}]
\end{eqnarray*}
As all $x_i$ are independent, it is
$$E\left((x_i-\mu)(x_1-\mu\right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
E\left((x_1-\mu)^2\right) = \sigma^2 & \mbox{ for }i=1 \\
E(x_i-\mu)\cdot E(x_1-\mu)=0 & \mbox{ for }i\neq 1
\end{array}\right.$$
It is thus
$$E(s'^2) = \sigma^2 -\frac{2}{n}\sigma^2 + \sigma^2 = 2\sigma^2\frac{n-1}{n}$$
An unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ is thus
$$\frac{n}{2(n-1)} s'^2 = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_1)^2$$
This in contradiction the the "degrees of freedom" argument, because only one variable ($x_1$) is reused in the formula and according to the "degress of freedom" heuristic, the denominator should be $(n-1)$ instead of $2(n-1)$.

**Caveat:** I have only proven that this is an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$, but have not yet verified this result with a Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the estimation of the expected value by calculating the average?

Comment: The statistical mean is a part of this formula, so it has something to do with it. The caclulation of the right hand side in the above equation is a bit tricky, and I do not see without doing the calculation, why the correction factor is exactly $(n-1)/n$. And I have not yet tried calculating it with a different unbiased estimator for the mean; I doubt, however, that the same correction factor will occur, which casts doubt on the entire concept of "degrees of freedom".

Comment: Out of curioity, I have just tried out the calculation with a different estimator for the mean, and the correction factor is different, which, I think, proves that the "degrees of freedom" argument is nonsense. I do not know, however, whether this counterexample is helpful for you, as you seem to be a beginner in statistics and presumably do not yet know the concepts of expectation value and unbiasedness.

Comment: Sorry I have to admit that I am even more confused than before 

Comment: I have just added the worked out counterxample, although it might lead to even more confusion....

Comment: Pardon, I don't understand your counterexample. You are estimating the mean from the sample of size 1 (i.e. the $x_1$), but then are estimating the variance from a different sample (of size n-1). Whereas the Bessel correction and the notion of "degrees of freedom" demand that both estimates - of the mean and the variance - should be made in the same sample.

Comment: Okay, I will need time process that, or even pick a pencil and recalculate it by myself. But thank you very much for your time and effort! Unfortunately I'm not attending any class, I am trying to teach my self since I need it during my PhD.

Comment: @ttnphns It is from the same sample, but the mean is a weighted average with all the weight put on the first sample.

Comment: @Zorg If you need it for your PhD and are only wondering, why the denominator is $(n-1)$ and not $n$ or 4(n-2)$, it is simply sufficient to know that this is a correction for obtaining on average the correct value. This is the concept of "unbiasedness".

Comment: @cdalitz, sorry. I can't take the "weighting" argument seriously.

Comment: @cdalitz actually I found the explanation of degrees of freedom better, just accepting that it is the way it is is a little bit disappointing. But I understand if there is no simple way to explain it to a beginner it may be the only way.

Comment: @Zorg "I found the explanation of degrees of freedom better" It lies in the eye of the beholder, whether felt knowledge is better than knowning not to know. I however would agree with the Gods' prophecy to Sokrates ;-)

Comment: @ttnphns You can distribute the weights in many ways (provided the resulting estimator for the mean remains unbiased, of course), and will obtain different correction factors. My point simply is that neither of these correction factors can be explained with the "degrees of freedom" argument. Or in other words: the "degrees of freedom" argument may only be used in cases in which it incidentally yields the correct result ;-)

Comment: I don't agree. The Bessel correction factor, which results in "n-1" denominator instead of "n" and makes the variance estimate unbiased, is directly linked to the notion of degrees-of-freedom.

Comment: @ttnphns Can you please explain how the "Bessel correction factor" is computed for an arbitrary unbiased estimate of the mean, e.g. one with 3/4 weight to the first half of samples and 1/4 of weight to the rest and what the "degrees of freedom" are in this case?

Comment: Sorry I cannot consider the weighting proposal of yours. As I said before I "don't take it serious" - your idea of arbitrary distributing weights. Perhaps you are mixing up "frequency weights" with "importance weights". As I said, I think you are not in the right to set some observations to zero weight and pretend that they are still in the sample after this.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the error propagation formula for the addition and subtraction
operations:

$s[x+y]^2 = s[x]^2 + s[y]^2 + 2 s[x,y]$

and

$s[x-y]^2 = s[x]^2 + s[y]^2 - 2 s[x,y]$

Therefore:

$s[x+y]^2 - s[x-y]^2 = 4 s[x,y]$

Expanding the left hand side of this equation:

\begin{align*}
  s[x+y]^2 - s[x-y]^2 & = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i} ([x_i+y_i]-[\bar{x}+\bar{y}])^2 - ([x_i-y_i]-[\bar{x}-\bar{y}])^2\\
  & = ... = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i} \left( 4 x_iy_i - 4x_i\bar{y} - 4y_i\bar{x} + 4\bar{x}\bar{y}\right) \\
  & = \frac{4}{n-1} \sum_{i}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})
\end{align*}

which proves that

$s[x,y] = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$